# Как лучше написать о нашей общей работе, или "Коллективное соучастие" бывает только в преступлениях?

Tags: оформление-книги

Над книгой работали:

Галина Аванесова и энтузиасты сайта «Русский язык»?

та же, но ...при коллективном соучастии энтузиастов - стекэксчейнджевцев-русистов?

или как?

или "коллективное соучастие" бывает только в преступлениях (как у меня выгуглилось)?

И куда бы пристроить https://rus.stackexchange.com/ ? и как лучше: rus.stackexchange.com?

Жду ваших предложений, мои дорогие сообщники! )))

Автор рада вас пригласить посмотреть, что получилось. С радостью рассмотрит любые предложения по нет-предела-совершенству, но внести правку сможет только в бумажный - следующеэтапный - вариант книги.

Милости просим [сюда](https://ridero.ru/books/obryvki_iz_realnostei_potegurim/) и [сюда](https://ridero.ru/books/obryvki_iz_realnostei_potegurim/#freeText).

---

P. S. Мы работаем уже в ПРО-аккаунте, куда внесена правка, но она не отобразилась в бесплатных страничках... Может, пока Инга не даст отмашку сайту (пока не дала)?

Comment: Мне первый вариант больше нравится, второй — ну совсем нет. :)

Comment: Тёмыч, надо слепить из закинутых слов нечто читабельное, но с упоминанием сайта: я написала менеджеру РидерО, как "нами пользоваться", т. е. их "бесплатные" авторы могут заглядывать на огонёк, ну и штатные редакторы с корректорами тоже не всезнайки. И Stack Exchange должен прозвучать, и Русский язык (филиал Стека)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Редактор Галина Аванесова и энтузиасты Stack Exchange «Русский язык» (https://rus.stackexchange.com).